# Hyperledger Fabric: Can multiple docker images corresponding to different versions exist side by side?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I would like to know if one installs hyperledger fabric 1.2 by running

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.2.0
```

and then follows it up by running

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.3.0
```

then will the second command wipe out the docker images corresponding to v1.2? If not, then in `docker-compose.yaml` when some code like `image: hyperledger/fabric-ca` is encountered, how does docker know which version of `hyperledger/fabric-ca` to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/install.html
The script does the following:

```
If needed, clone the hyperledger/fabric-samples repository 
Checkout the appropriate version tag 
Install the Hyperledger Fabric platform-specific binaries and config files for the version specified into the /bin and /config directories of fabric-samples 
Download the Hyperledger Fabric docker images for the version specified
```

Passing 1.2.0 would download the corresponding docker images and additionally mark them as 'latest'. 
Similarly, passing 1.3.0 would download the corresponding docker images and additionally mark them as 'latest'. Other images would not be deleted (from what I see in the script).

Now, when you specify `image: hyperledger/fabric-ca` in the docker-compose file, docker will automatically look for the `latest` tag (first locally, then in the registry).
Since the bootstrap script has been run for the required version, the corresponding image would be marked as latest, even if a newer version of that image is available locally - this would happen if you run 1.3.0 first, followed by 1.2.0 (1.2.0 would be tagged with latest)

The following is `docker image ls` after running `1.2.0`, followed by `1.3.0` and then again `1.3.0`

```
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     1.3.0               2476cefaf833        6 weeks ago         1.7GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     latest              2476cefaf833        6 weeks ago         1.7GB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          1.3.0               5c6b20ba944f        6 weeks ago         244MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              5c6b20ba944f        6 weeks ago         244MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.3.0               c056cd9890e7        6 weeks ago         1.5GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              c056cd9890e7        6 weeks ago         1.5GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       1.3.0               953124d80237        6 weeks ago         1.38GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       latest              953124d80237        6 weeks ago         1.38GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     1.3.0               f430f581b46b        6 weeks ago         145MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     latest              f430f581b46b        6 weeks ago         145MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.3.0               f3ea63abddaa        6 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              f3ea63abddaa        6 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   0.4.13              e62e0af39193        7 weeks ago         1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   latest              e62e0af39193        7 weeks ago         1.39GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       0.4.13              4121ea662c47        7 weeks ago         1.4GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       latest              4121ea662c47        7 weeks ago         1.4GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     0.4.13              1d3266e01e64        7 weeks ago         1.45GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     latest              1d3266e01e64        7 weeks ago         1.45GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       1.2.0               379602873003        4 months ago        1.51GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       1.2.0               6acf31e2d9a4        4 months ago        1.43GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     1.2.0               4baf7789a8ec        4 months ago        152MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        1.2.0               82c262e65984        4 months ago        159MB
```

Comment: Thanks. re: docker will automatically look for the latest tag (first locally, then in the registry). How does one tell docker to use a specific version? Also could you explain the part about first locally, then in the registry? Does locally mean the machine from where program is executed? And registry is remote central repo? If image does not exist locally is it dynamically downloaded from registry at runtime without user having to do anything special for the download to happen?

Comment: For a specific version of the image, you would specify this `image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.3.0` in the docker-compose file. Yes, locally means the local machine from which the docker commands are being executed. Registry is usually the docker hub or your private registry. When you perform a `docker pull <image_name>`, the image is stored somewhere locally. These images show up under `docker image ls`. And yes, user does not have to do anything as long as there is connectivity to the registry.

Comment: For ex: `docker run hello-world` will check locally if the image is present, then try to download from docker hub. Once the image is available locally it will run it.